# How Can I Use Upside Numpad?

Tags: autohotkey

I am using **AutoHotkey**. [**This Program**](http://www.autohotkey.com/) I want to use left side numpad in my script but I couldn't use it.This case is important because I play a game and that game use left side numpad,not right side. (Right side numpad doesn't work in this game) [image: This leftside Numpad]

This is my code;

```cpp
SendMode Input

~control::

Loop  

{

    if GetKeyState("e")  ; If this statement is true, the user has physically released the F1 key.

        break  ; Break out of the loop.

    send,{Numpad8}

    Sleep 200

    send,1

    Sleep 200

}

return
```

*Any idea?*

**Edit =** I don't know how can I show this problem. How can you understand this `Send command` press left side's numpad or right side? I play *Knight Online* game and I can try these methods in the game.Code works or not.But could you try it ?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want pressing `Numpad1` to imitate sending the `1` key on the left side of the keyboard and so on?

Comment: I think your question was downvoted because it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Left side numpad and right side numpad has a difference in some programs or games. Some games perceive left numpad,some games perceive right numpad. Because of this,it's really important question. For example Knight Online game perceive left side numpad.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have all the keys AutoHotkey handles:
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

Just change `send,{Numpad8}` to `Send,{1}`

You can also try to simulate a keypress this way (The last time I used AutoHotkey I had to do it):

```
Send, {1 down}
Sleep 100
Send, {1 up}
```

And also, you can try to send the keystrokes directly to the window this way:

```
wintitle = WINDOW TITLE

Controlsend,,{1 down}, %wintitle%
Sleep 100
Controlsend,,{1 up}, %wintitle%
```

THe window title can be the starting characters of the window. For example, if the window title is "This is a game", you can set as window title in your script "This is a".

Comment: I don't think so. I tried your method in my game and program still doesn't press left numpad. Could that about `Send Method` ?

Comment: @TeachMeJava I've edited my answer. Also, note that the 1 key is between brackets. In your code you send 1 without brackets.